# Resetting Password

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my user table I have a column called code. If a user has clicked on the forgotten password link and enters in email and then clicks on submit. It then **updates the code** on to the **database row matching the email**.

I have another controller called Forgotten which handles the `$code` and `editCode` that works fine.

The problem I am having is I have tried a few times and will not edit/change password. I currently have removed non working code.

I need to be able to check make sure the `$code = URI Segment 3` matches the `code` and `email` on that database row. And then allows me to update/change password.

**Controller Reset**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Reset extends MX_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  if ($this->user->hasPermissionAccess() == TRUE) {
     $this->lang->load('admin/english', 'english');
     $this->lang->load('admin/common/reset', 'english');
     $this->load->library('settings');
     $this->load->library('pagination');
     $this->load->library('request');
     $this->load->library('response');
     $this->load->library('document');
             $this->load->library('email');
  } else { 
    redirect('admin/error');
  }
}

public function index() {
    $this->document->setTitle($this->lang->line('heading_title'));

    $data['heading_title'] = $this->lang->line('heading_title');

    $data['text_password'] = $this->lang->line('text_password');

    $data['entry_password'] = $this->lang->line('entry_password');
    $data['entry_confirm'] = $this->lang->line('entry_confirm');

    $data['button_save'] = $this->lang->line('button_save');
    $data['button_cancel'] = $this->lang->line('button_cancel');

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>' .' '.  $this->lang->line('text_home'),
        'href' => site_url('common/dashboard')
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->lang->line('heading_title'),
        'href' => site_url('common/forgotten')
    );

    if (!empty($this->request->post['password'])) {
        $data['password'] = $this->request->post['password'];
    } else {
        $data['password'] = '';
    }

    if (!empty($this->request->post['confirm_password'])) {
        $data['confirm_password'] = $this->request->post['confirm_password'];
    } else {
        $data['confirm_password'] = '';
    }

    $data['action'] = site_url('admin/reset') .'/'. $this->uri->segment(3);

    $data['cancel'] = site_url('admin/login');



    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password','required|trim|xss_clean|matches[confirm]|min_length[3]|max_length[25]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|trim');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        return $this->load->view('common/reset', $data);

    } else {

        $this->load->model('admin/user/users_model');

        $code = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $user_info = $this->users_model->getUserByCode($code);

        if($user_info) {
            $this->load->model('admin/user/users_model');
            $this->users_model->editUser($user_info['user_id'], $this->request->post, $data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You have now updated your Password!');
            redirect('admin');
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Unable to submit changes. Please try again!');
            redirect('admin');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users_model extends CI_Model {

public function addUser($data) {
 $user_insert = array(
  'user_group_id' => "10",
  'username' => $data['username'],
  'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
  'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
  'email' => $data['email'],
  'password' => $this->hash($data['password']),
  'status' => $data['status'],
  'date_added' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
);

$this->db->insert_id();
$this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'user', $user_insert);
}

public function editUser($user_id, $data) {
$data['last_updated'] = mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now());

if (isset($data['password']) && $data['password']) {
  $data['password'] = $this->hash($data['password']);
} else {
  unset($data['password']);
}

$this->db->where('user_id', $user_id)->update('user', $data);
return $user_id;
}

public function getUserByCode($code) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "user` 
    WHERE code = '" . $this->db->escape($code) . "' AND code != ''");

    return $query->row_array();
}

public function hash($password) {
$this->load->library('PasswordHash', array('iteration_count_log2' => 8, 'portable_hashes' => FALSE));
return $this->passwordhash->HashPassword($password);
}

public function editCode($email, $code) {
    $this->db->where('email', $this->request->post['email']);
    $this->db->set('code', $code);
    $this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');
}
}
```

Comment: You are passing the $email to the function editCode but you are using the request class to get it.. try replace to the $email param...

Comment: I have another controller called forgotten that is where edit code is used. Reset Controller only controls update/changing  of the password.

Comment: Just a thought, you may consider using [TankAuth](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) which does *all* of this for you.

Comment: No I use my own tank to bulk plus I have my own permission controller functions. Do not want to use any other out siders.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You want to check if $code matches the uri segment? If it does, change the password if not throw up an error.

Comment: @Craig I updated the controller and model what I have been trying. But form not submitting And code which is $this->uri->segment(3) must match code column with the user row id in the user table.

Comment: Just a quick change. Shouldn't it be $this->input->post() rather then $this->request->post()

Comment: I have only custom post lib some times codeigniter post does not do what I am after it performs the same.

Comment: @Craig I have solved issue worked hard at it past half hour

Comment: That's good. What was the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63595/discussion-between-acoderslife-and-craig).

Answer (score 0):

I have been working hard at problem solving last half hour but have figured out why I need to do a couple of edit password separate from edit user and added get by code.

New controller and model methods down below for my resetting password. I still have a separate forgotten controller that handles the reset code

Model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users_model extends CI_Model {

  public function addUser($data) {
    $user_insert = array(
      'user_group_id' => "10",
      'username' => $data['username'],
      'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
      'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
      'email' => $data['email'],
      'password' => $this->hash($data['password']),
      'status' => $data['status'],
      'date_added' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
    );

    $this->db->insert_id();
    $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'user', $user_insert);
    }

    public function editUser($user_id, $data) {
    $data['last_updated'] = mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now());

    if (isset($data['password']) && $data['password']) {
      $data['password'] = $this->hash($data['password']);
    } else {
      unset($data['password']);
    }

    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id)->update('user', $data);
    return $user_id;
    }

    public function editPassword($user_id, $password) {

        $data['password'] = $this->request->post['password'];

        $this->db->query("UPDATE `" . $this->db->dbprefix . "user` 
        SET  
        password = " . $this->db->escape($this->hash($data['password'])) . ", 
        code = '' 
        WHERE 
        user_id = '" . (int)$user_id . "'");
    }

    public function hash($password) {
    $this->load->library('PasswordHash', array('iteration_count_log2' => 8, 'portable_hashes' => FALSE));
    return $this->passwordhash->HashPassword($password);
    }

    public function editCode($email, $code) {
        $this->db->where('email', $this->request->post['email']);
        $this->db->set('code', $code);
        $this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');
    }

    public function deleteUser($user_id) {
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->delete($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');
    }

    public function getUser($user_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, (SELECT ug.name FROM `" . $this->db->dbprefix . "user_group` ug WHERE ug.user_group_id = u.user_group_id) AS user_group FROM `" . $this->db->dbprefix . "user` u WHERE u.user_id = '" . (int)$user_id . "'");
    return $query->row_array();
    }

    public function getUserByUsername($username) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . $this->db->dbprefix . "user` WHERE username = ". $this->db->escape($username) ." ");
    return $query->row();
    }

    public function getUserByCode($code) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . $this->db->dbprefix . "user` 
        WHERE code = " . $this->db->escape($code) . " AND code != ''");

        return $query->row_array();
    }

  public function getUsers() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
      return $query->result_array();
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

    public function getTotalUsers() {
    return $this->db->count_all('user');
  }

  public function getTotalUsersByGroupId($user_group_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `" . $this->db->dbprefix . "user` WHERE user_group_id = '" . (int)$user_group_id . "'");
    return $query->row_array('total');
  }

  public function getTotalUsersByEmail($email) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `" . $this->db->dbprefix . "user` WHERE LCASE(email) = " . $this->db->escape($email) . " ");

        return $query->row_array('total');
  }


}
```

Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Reset extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
      if ($this->user->hasPermissionAccess() == TRUE) {
         $this->lang->load('admin/english', 'english');
         $this->lang->load('admin/common/reset', 'english');
         $this->load->library('settings');
         $this->load->library('pagination');
         $this->load->library('request');
         $this->load->library('response');
         $this->load->library('document');
                 $this->load->library('email');
      } else { 
        redirect('admin/error');
      }
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->document->setTitle($this->lang->line('heading_title'));

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->lang->line('heading_title');

        $data['text_password'] = $this->lang->line('text_password');

        $data['entry_password'] = $this->lang->line('entry_password');
        $data['entry_confirm'] = $this->lang->line('entry_confirm');

        $data['button_save'] = $this->lang->line('button_save');
        $data['button_cancel'] = $this->lang->line('button_cancel');

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>' .' '.  $this->lang->line('text_home'),
            'href' => site_url('common/dashboard')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->lang->line('heading_title'),
            'href' => site_url('common/forgotten')
        );

        if (isset($this->request->post['password'])) {
            $data['password'] = $this->request->post['password'];
        } else {
            $data['password'] = '';
        }

        $data['action'] = site_url('admin/reset') .'/'. $this->uri->segment(3);

        $data['cancel'] = site_url('admin/login');

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password','required|trim|xss_clean|matches[confirm_password]|min_length[3]|max_length[25]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|trim');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            return $this->load->view('common/reset', $data);

        } else {

            $this->load->model('admin/user/users_model');

            $code = $this->uri->segment(3);

            $user_info = $this->users_model->getUserByCode($code);

            if($user_info) {
                $this->load->model('admin/user/users_model');
                $this->users_model->editPassword($user_info['user_id'], $this->request->post['password']);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You have now updated your Password!');
                redirect('admin');
                return true;
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Unable to submit changes. Please try again!');
                redirect('admin');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```